# Range argument with combination of cells and another range

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote something that is designed to define a dynamic range based on standard last row stuff and also xlspecialcellslastcell to clear out any extraneous data.  However, when I try to put these together, I get an error and I can't work out why.  I checked and both of the arguments I'm passing to the range property are strings so I thought that that would work.

```
ws.Range(Cells(LastRow + 1, 1).Address, ws.Range("a1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Address)
```

When I print just the second part of the range argument above, I get an address as a string.  When I print the first part of the argument above, I also get an address as a string.  If I do a similar setup but instead of using the range property, I used cells.address again, it works fine.  I feel that this should be obvious!

Thank you!

Comment: `Cells(LastRow + 1, 1).Address` is not necessarily in the same worksheet as `ws`. Change it to `ws.Cells(LastRow + 1, 1).Address` Also you don't need the `.Address` in both, you can just give the cells to the `Range`.

Comment: Oof, that's embarrassing!  Thank you!  How would I know that that was the issue?  I did some testing with it and you're absolutely right - if I specify no ws for any of the arguments, it works but gives me a weird address.  If I specify one with a ws and one without, it gives me an application defined or object defined error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that in

```
ws.Range(Cells(LastRow + 1, 1).Address, ws.Range("a1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Address)
```

the `Cells(LastRow + 1, 1)` and `ws.Range("a1")` are not necessarily both in the same worksheet `ws`. That means of course alone they work properly but if you try to use them in as one range, that range cannot begin in `sheet 1` and end in `sheet 2`. A range needs to be in one sheet only.

Therefore you get an *"application defined or object defined error"*.

If you follow one rule:

> *Never use any objects that are located in a worksheet* (`Range`, `Cells`, `Columns`, `Rows`, etc) *without explicitly specifying the workbook and worksheet.*

Then you are safe against these issues.

The solution is

```
ws.Range(ws.Cells(LastRow + 1, 1), ws.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell))
```